# Check box like functionality in table using query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a primary table with multiple records for the name but different quantity and colors.

**TblPrimary**: current table

```
id | name    | color | Quan  |
===+=========+=======+=======+
1  | Apple   | Red   | 10    |
2  | Banana  | Yellow| 5     |
3  | Mango   | Yellow| 8     |
4  | Apple   | Green | 20    |
5  | Banana  | Brown | 15    |
6  | Mango   | Orange| 12    |
7  | Mango   | Green |  5    |
```

This is my main table and I basically want data from the primary table like this. So basically the `Quan` in main table is sum of all individual `Quan` from the primary table. The colors (Red,Yellow,Brown) in the main table; are bits which indicate whether that color is present for the fruit or not in the primary table.

**TblMain**: new expected table

```
id | Name    | Quan  | Red | Yellow | Brown | Green | Orange |
===+=========+=======+=====+========+=======+=======+========+
1  | Apple   |  30   |  1  |   0    |  0    |   1   |  0     |
2  | Banana  |  20   |  0  |   1    |  1    |   0   |  0     |
3  | Mango   |  25   |  0  |   1    |  0    |   1   |  1     |
```

I have got the below query and I have group by and the sum. I am not able to get the colors portion of the main table populated.

```
INSERT INTO TblMain(Name, Quan)
    (SELECT Name, SUM(Quan)
     FROM TblPrimary
     GROUP BY Name)
```

Comment: What is your desired output?  I can't tell from reading your initial question.

Comment: I think `TblMain` is his desired output.

Comment: I hope this is academic as this is a terrible idea for a database design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `sum` windows function in subquery then use condition aggregate function make your expect result.

```
select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) id,
        name,
    Quan, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Red',
    SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Yellow' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Yellow',
    SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Brown' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Brown',
    SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Green',
    SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Orange' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Orange'
from (
    SELECT name,
    color,
    SUM(Quan) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name) Quan  
    FROM TblPrimary
) t1
group by name,Quan
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7088e29be51d8eeab90b7cd6480e9e1a)

**Result**

```
id  name    Quan    Red Yellow  Brown   Green   Orange
1   Apple   30      1   0       0       1       0
2   Banana  20      0   1       1       0       0
3   Mango   25      0   1       0       1       1
```

Comment: Works as expected. Thank you. Did not know sum could be used with a GroupBy

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIVOT  to convert values to columns. In your case this becomes a bit cumbersome, because you want the row sum as well as well as the 0/1 flags

```
SELECT
    name,
    ISNULL(Red,0) + ISNULL(Yellow,0) + ISNULL(Brown,0) + ISNULL(Green,0) + ISNULL(Orange,0) As Quan,
    CASE WHEN Red IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Red,
    CASE WHEN Yellow IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Yellow,
    CASE WHEN Brown IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Brown,
    CASE WHEN Green IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Green,
    CASE WHEN Orange IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Orange
FROM  
  (SELECT name, color, Quan  
   FROM dbo.TblPrimary) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
   SUM(Quan)
FOR color IN (Red, Yellow, Brown, Green, Orange)  
) AS PivotTable;
```

If you display the sums directly for the colors instead of the flags, the query simplifies to:

```
SELECT
    name, Red, Yellow, Brown, Green, Orange
FROM  
  (SELECT name, color, Quan  
   FROM dbo.TblPrimary) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
   SUM(Quan)
FOR color IN (Red, Yellow, Brown, Green, Orange)  
) AS PivotTable;
```

And the result will be:

```
name     Red  Yellow  Brown  Green  Orange
==========================================
Apple     10   null    null   20     null
Banana   null   5       15   null    null
Mango    null   8      null    5      12
```